# Laravel: How to protect resources from access by other users?

Tags: php, laravel, security, authentication, authorization

I'm wondering how to protect resources from access by other users with Laravel.

For example if I have this scenario:

- User 1 has a resource with id 1
- User 2 has a resource with id 2

how can I protect access of resource 2 from user 1?

An example is accessing a resource for edit via this URL:

http://localhost:8000/resource/2/edit

Does Laravel has a feature to do that or should I manually check the ownership in every Controller's method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *should I manually check the ownership in every Controller's method?* Not in every method, you use a **middleware** for a group of URLs or for your controller action

Comment: try to see https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create [policy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#creating-policies) for that :

```
public function update(User $user, Resource $resource)
{
    return $user->id == $resource->user_id; //for example
}
```

then you can add it as middleware to your edit route :

```
Route::get('resource/{resource}/edit', ResourceController@edit)->middleware('can:update,resource');
```

Ps: that's just an example in the documentation there are many usful things that can help you

Comment: Yes it is! Thanks Maraboc